# DateTime->format(epoch) returning the wrong date

Tags: php, datetime

I am working on a project and I am having an issue formatting an epoch time to a human readable time.

I have the following epoch time `1428512160` and when I put this through epochconverter.com I get the human time of `08/04/2015 17:56:00 GMT+1:00 DST` as expected.

I then use the following code in order to perform the conversion from the epoch time to a human date time.

```
$dt = new DateTime($supportDetails["Reported"]);
$reportedTimeString = $dt->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

$supportDetails[Reported] is the epoch time (I've printed it so I know it's correct).

The result I get back however is `08-04-2160 14:28:51`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add an `@` for the timestamp in the DateTime class, like this:

```
$dt = new DateTime("@" . $supportDetails["Reported"]);
                  //^ See here
```

You can also see this in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php). And a quote from there:

> **Unix Timestamp** **"@"** "-"? [0-9]+ "@1215282385"

Also note that the current timezone is getting ignored, which you can also see in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php#refsect1-datetime.construct-parameters):

> **Note:**
>   The **$timezone parameter and the current timezone are ignored** when the **$time** parameter either is a **UNIX timestamp** (e.g. **@946684800**) or specifies a timezone (e.g. 2010-01-28T15:00:00+02:00).

Comment: Thanks, I missed the @ in the manual. What's the meaning of the @ it seems a bit odd, I can't see the reason for the manual

Comment: @Boardy You're welcome! I think it's just a "random character" which you normally don't use in a normal date. But I also don't know the exact reason

Answer (score 0):

Printing date and time is correct.
Its based on what GMT you have set in your PHP.
If you printing with GMT you will get required result.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

`$reportedTimeString = date("d-m-Y H:i:s", $supportDetails["Reported"]);`

Or the following:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp($supportDetails["Reported"]);
$reportedTimeString = $date->format("d-m-Y H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is with your formatting.

If you look at [PHP's date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) you can see that you just need to write each portion of the desired date & time into a string.

The following formatting gives the same output you were looking for:

`$dt = new DateTime($supportDetails["Reported"]);
$reportedTimeString = $dt->format('d/m/Y H:i:s \G\M\TP T');`